# Find form that contains element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element inside a form, there might be many elements between them. Having a variable pointing to my element, I want to know how to get the parent form in a variable.

EG:

```
<form>
  <div>
    //Element
  </div>
</div>
```

So having `var element` pointing to an element inside the divs, how can I get the form that contains it?

I'm thinking on looping through parents until finding a form, but I want to know if there's an easier way. How can I get the form element?

Comment: The easiest way is using jQuery `.closest()` method, which in pure JavaScript does exactly the same: goes up the tree in loop and finds the first matched element.

Comment: I'm not using jQuery. So I should just loop to the parent? Thanks

Comment: Exactly so. No other way I'm afraid.

Comment: So you need to first find your element, and after got this, get the `form` by `element.parentNode` until you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript function to achieve this :

```
function ParentForm(element){ 
  var parent = elem.parentNode; 
  if(parent && parent.tagName != 'FORM'){
     parent = findParentForm(parent);
     }
  return parent;
}
var myForm = parentForm(myElement)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple to do this:

```
var lookup = element;
while(lookup && lookup.nodeName != "FORM") lookup = lookup.parentNode;
if( lookup) {
    // lookup if your form
}
```

I have this in a function in my projects, called "findParent", that accepts a callback to test if the element is the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5 it would be

```
<input element>.form
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5QAR/)

[HTML5 - 4.10 Forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form)
*A form-associated element is, by default, associated with its nearest ancestor form element (as described below), but, if it is reassociateable, may have a form attribute specified to override this*

Comment: +1 Nice catch! However it won't work for non input elements: http://jsfiddle.net/7xSvR/.

Comment: You're right. I've assumed the mentioned `//Element` is an input element. For anything else you would have to use the already mentioned DOM traversal.