# How to enable middle clicking of postback hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, userscripts

OK, so I am dealing with website that uses ASP.NET Web Forms. It contains lots of hyperlinks that contain a href of the form `javascript:__doPostBack(...` which is incredibly annoying because you cannot middle click the hyperlink to open the page in a new window like you would with an ordinary hyperlink. I am trying to come up with a userscript that will fix this. So far I have come up with this, which seems to work for the most part. The one caveat I have run into is that sometime if I middle click a link to open a new window and then try to click another postback link on the original page it sometimes takes me to the wrong page.

Does anyone know of a better way to handle this?

```
let form = document.querySelector('form');
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for (let link of links) {
    if (link.href.startsWith('javascript:')) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if (e.button === 1) {
                form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                eval(this.href.slice(11));
                form.removeAttribute('target');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Too unwieldy for a comment so here's a partial answer...</sup>

Issues:

1. The question really needs an MCVE which, in this case, would be the question's code PLUS a link to an offending website.
   For your big issue (links going to wrong place) this is especially required.

   Note that the site may also be operating as a state machine (generally a poor practice) such that your only recourse *might* be to auto-reload the original page (in a real, hidden, or popup manner) before firing the misbehaving links. Asp.net and banking sites are particularly bad about this kind of design.
2. The code assumes that there is only one form. This is not a good assumption even if it's true when you spot-check a page at one point.
3. Get rid of `document.querySelector('form');` and:
   A) Use `let links = document.querySelectorAll("form a[href*='doPostBack']");`
   B) Find the parent form from within the click callback.  See logic for that at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22509461/331508).
   C) The anonymous function in a loop is a performance issue. Use a named function, defined outside the loop.
   D) Use of `eval()` will allow malicious JS to do unspeakable evil.  Parse the 1 or 2 arguments to `__doPostBack()`. They are always strings. Then call `window.__doPostBack()` or `unsafeWindow.__doPostBack()` directly.
4. That approach does not work with controls created via AJAX techniques. But this does not seem to be needed in your case.

Comment: 1. Sorry I can't provide a link since the site in question is not public. 2. I know nothing about ASP.NET Web Forms but I think a limitation is that you are limited to one form (the entire page is one big form). Also, there is no AJAX anywhere (unfortunately).

Comment: Plain vanilla asp.net has a default one-form scheme. But people have been [working around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663355/asp-net-more-than-1-form) that for years. It's a bad assumption to build into any code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think it is definitely an issue with state. Calling `window.location.reload()` on the parent page "fixes" the issue with some links no longer directing you to the correct page, but refreshing the page every time you middle click a link feels wrong. My workaround is to open a new window and clone the DOM over to it from the patent. Then I find the link that was middle clicked in the parent and simulate a left click on it. Very hackish but this seems to work.